# Cooling a GPU whose fan is blocked by PCI card

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, fan, cooling

First, I am using the NZXT Phantom 410 Mid tower for my system. I currently have a small [NVIDIA GT710](https://www.evga.com/products/product.aspx?pn=02G-P3-2712-RX) with passive cooling (heatsink) and I am about to get a [ZOTAC GTX 1080 Ti AMP Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XXVVQYH). I want to have both GPUs installed.

The issue is that if I install the 1080 Ti on the x16 PCI lane where my current GPU is, then the only option for the GT710 is 3 slots lower (x8 PCI). Since the new card is quite thick, if I place them like this they will be very close to each other like 1cm or less. As a result the GT710 will be mostly covering one of the two fans of the 1080 Ti. Note that in this tower, the PSU is located at the bottom just a bit lower than the last PCI lane. This PSU is flowing air upwards.

I wanted to ask whether this is OK or it can damage my new GPU in the long term due to insufficient cooling.

There are mounting holes for a 140mm fan on the side of the case. I can install a fan there and set it to blow air either to or from the PCI lanes area of the motherboard but I don't know whether this can help.

I would appreciate it if you can also suggest some software/methods to test what is going on with the temperatures in each scenario.

Comment: Do the fan openings blow air out (so blow hot air onto the other card, or be blocked a little), or suck air in (so a 1cm space might be more than enough)?

Comment: It appears to me that most GPU designs these days, while the fans face the front/top of the card, pull most air in from the end of the card and exhaust it out the read of the computer case. Considering many major computer builders routinely place two GPUs very close to each other in this very configuration indicates this is an acceptable layout. That said, there are monitoring tools for expressly this purpose: to test that your layout allows sufficient airflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine.  I run a similar setup (i.e. one GPU immediately on top of the fans of another GPU with a very small gap between the cards.)  Internal blowers don't really move the hot air in any particular direction other than across and then away from the GPU heat sink to another part of the case.  It's the job of your case fans to ensure airflow through the case to actually get the hot air out of there.

Since you're running nVidia cards, just use their monitoring software and look at the GPU temps on both cards when running under load.  I'm running on Linux so that's the NVIDIA X Server Settings application -> GPU # -> Thermal Settings.  In my case, the 'top' card (i.e. vertically above the other card in the case) runs 5-10C warmer since the lower card is dumping a bit of heat on it via convection.  As long as your thermals look good, it's not a problem.

Note that even if your thermals get a bit too high, the 1080 will throttle to keep your card within a safe range.  So your main potential downside is that you won't overclock as high or possibly might throttle a bit.  The easiest way to avoid that, should that occur, is to lower the ambient temperature of the room the system is running in.

Edit: I forgot to address the last part of your question.  In order to determine what the delta will be from adding the 2nd card, remove the lower card (which will be obstructing the fans of the upper card), close up the case and then get some readings both after the card has been idle for ~5 minutes and then under load.  Reinsert the lower card and close the case back up and repeat the readings.  That will get you the thermal delta (i.e. the 'cost') of adding that second card.  Adding additional case fans can help, but see if there's even an issue before bothering.